# Stored procedure not setting variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have tried but do not understand what is wrong with my code. I am trying to set a variable within a stored procedure calling a second stored procedure but as I know the result I know that the variable is not set correctly. Can anyone say where is my mistake.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ColumnHasData]
    @scheme VARCHAR(10),
    @tablename VARCHAR(30),
    @column VARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @FullQuery NVARCHAR (max)=N'
        IF EXISTS
        (
            SELECT *
            FROM ' + @scheme + '.' + @tablename + '
            WHERE [' + @column + '] IS NOT NULL
        )
        SELECT CAST(1 AS BIT)
        ELSE 
        SELECT CAST(0 AS BIT)
    ';

    EXECUTE sp_executesql @FullQuery;
END

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[me_delete_column]
AS
BEGIN

    Declare @noDataPresent bit
    
    exec @noDataPresent = [different_db].[dbo].[ColumnHasData] 'int' ,'table1' ,'column1'

    print @noDataPresent

    RETURN
    IF(@noDataPresent=0)
    begin
        --drop column
    end
    
END
```

`ColumnHasData` is on one database

`me_delete_column` is on a second database

I am trying to set variable `@noDataPresent` executing `ColumnHasData`

Even though I know the result should be `1` the `print @noDataPresent` returns `0` so something is wrong.

What is wrong and why my variable is not setting? The SQL Server is version 15.0.4102.2

Comment: Your procedure `dbo.ColumnHasData` doesn't return anything? To "return" a value (which is intended to be the status of the SP), requires use of the `RETURN` statement.

Comment: You don't use the *resultset* returned by the procedure but call it as if it was returning a *returncode*, which is always an *int*.

Comment: So I should set a variable to be returned with `sp_executesql ` and then return it?

Comment: That procedure is **dangerous**; it is wide open to injection attacks. If you *must* use dynamic SQL **always** properly quote your objects with `QUOTENAME`. Though this look like you've tried to create a "one size fits all" dynamic procedure, which is rarely a good idea. SQL isn't a scripting language, don't write it like one.

Comment: @HellOfACode you really need to read the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/create-a-stored-procedure?view=sql-server-ver15) to discover the different between an output parameter, a return value, and a resultset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an output parameter to pass a scalar value from a stored procedure.  The only mildly-tricky part is setting the parameter in dynamic SQL.

EG

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ColumnHasData]
    @schema NVARCHAR(128),
    @tablename NVARCHAR(128),
    @column NVARCHAR(128),
    @hasData bit output
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @FullQuery NVARCHAR (max)=N'
        IF EXISTS
        (
            SELECT *
            FROM ' + quotename(@schema) + '.' + quotename(@tablename) + '
            WHERE ' + quotename(@column) + ' IS NOT NULL
        )
        set @hasData = CAST(1 AS BIT)
        ELSE 
        set @hasData = CAST(0 AS BIT)
    ';

    EXECUTE sp_executesql @FullQuery, N'@hasData bit output', @hasData = @hasData output;
END
```

Sample data

```
use tempdb 
drop table if exists t 
create table t(id int, a int null)
insert into t(id,a) values (1,null)
```

Usage:

```
declare @hasData bit
exec ColumnHasData 'dbo','t','id', @hasData output

select @hasdata 

declare @hasData bit
exec ColumnHasData 'dbo','t','a', @hasData output

select @hasdata
```